# Why values are not equal?

Tags: php, session, captcha

index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<img src='captcha.php' />
<?php
var_dump($_SESSION['vercode']);
unset($_SESSION['vercode']);
?>
```

captcha.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["vercode"] = rand(10000,99999); 
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("img/bg.jpg");
$txtColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($image, 5, 5, 5, $_SESSION["vercode"], $txtColor);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

On result page, value on the image is not equal to value on the var_dump.

Please advice why they are not equal and how can fix it?

Comment: Try change img src by random string.like captcha.php?t=12548.maybe browser cache.

Comment: Are there any news? Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

This does not work because index.php works first and captcha.php works second.
At the time index.php prints its session variables, captcha.php has not yet been called at all. Index.php outputs the string `<img src='captcha.php' />` but this is only a string, not a call to captcha.php. This string will go into browser and browser will call captcha.php when it needs to render the image. But it will be AFTER the index.php finished its output so its session variables will be unaffected.

To fix it, add `$_SESSION["vercode"] = rand(10000,99999);` into index.php, not into captcha.php. This way captcha.php will read `vercode` from a session prepared by index.php and all values will match.

Also, don't unset `vercode` in index, because you will have nothing to check when user sends the captcha answer. Unset (reset) it only after you get answer from user or before generating a new captcha.

Also, if you receive user answer into the same index.php, you need not to reset the captcha in this case. Something like:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $vercode = $_SESSION["vercode"];
    // process user input...
} else {
    // reset vercode
    $_SESSION["vercode"] = rand(10000,99999);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to get your code to work with minimal changes (this is nothing, I would use in production) and to illustrate the problem:
index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["vercode"] = rand(10000,99999);
session_write_close();
?>
<img src='captcha.php' />
<?php
var_dump($_SESSION['vercode']);
unset($_SESSION['vercode']);
```

captcha.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("img/bg.jpg");
$txtColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
imagestring($image, 5, 5, 5, $_SESSION["vercode"], $txtColor);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

The Problem: You open the session twice. So when a new random number in captcha.php is generated, the value of $_SESSION["vercode"] does not change in index.php, because the variable is not refreshed from the session file (For that you have to use session_write_close).
 => You can see that var_dump always prints the previous generated random number.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to create captcha try this

```
<?php
$ranStr = md5(microtime());
$ranStr = substr($ranStr, 0, 6);
?>
<img src="scripts/captcha.php?df='<?php echo $ranStr; ?>'" alt="captcha" width="102" height="53" />
          <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ranStr; ?>" name="cap" id="cap" />
```

here is captcha.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$ranStr= ltrim($_REQUEST['df']);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg("images/bg.jpg");
$txtColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
imagestring($image, 5, 5, 5, $ranStr, $txtColor);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Comment: the difference is due to difference in miliseconds of executing both commands

Comment: The OP asks why the values are not equal, not how to create captcha.

Comment: I was stucked in the same problem, dats y i m guiding him the alternative to  acomplish his task